# Calculating light in tangent space

Tags: directx11

Just a simple question.
To do lighting in tangent space, just take the transpose of the TBN basis Matrix and multiply that against the light direction.

Is that right?
Here is my code

```
 float3 normalT = 2.0f*normalMapSample - 1.0f;

    // Build orthonormal basis.
    float3 N = pin.NormalW;
    float3 T = normalize(pin.TangentW - dot(pin.TangentW, N)*N);
    float3 B = cross(N, T);

    float3x3 TBN = float3x3(T, B, N);
    TBN = transpose(TBN);

    float3 bumpedNormalW = mul(normalT, TBN);
```

AND

```
float diffuseFactor = dot(lightVec, bumpedNormalW);
```

Is that right because I'm getting my grid all dark. the rest of the scene seems to be right.